# Why is $2^n +1=(2+1)(2^{n-1} - 2^{n-2} +2^{n-3}-\ldots+1)$ for odd $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This transformation is only a part of solution of my problem but the most significant one.
I need to show that $2^n+1$ is divisible by $3$ for odd $n$’s.
I have exercised polynomial transformation for two weeks and I did geometric progression for a week, but I can’t still easily come up to this transformation.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The last term is a geometric series

Answer (score 2):

Take in general the polynomial
$$x^n+1$$

When n is odd we have -1 as a root doing long division we get

$$x^n+1=(x+1)(x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}\cdots-x+1)$$

For a more intuitive feel look at what happens when you expand RHS

$$
(x+1)(x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}\cdots+1)\\=(x^n-x^{n-1}\cdots-x^2+x)+(x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}\cdots-x+1)
$$

Every term other than $x^n$ and 1 exactly cancel out in both brackets

$x=2$ gives your identity

Comment: x^n + 1=(x+1)(x^n−1 − x^n−2⋯−x+1) I dont even understand this part

Comment: @GreyCow if you are familiar with the sum of gp formula this was a soft derivation for it

Comment: You get the common formula when u divide by (x+1) on both sides for a=1 r=-x

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that $2^{2n-1} +1$ is divisible by $3$ for all $n$.  Obviously this holds for $n = 1$.  Now

$$2^{2(n+1)-1}+1=4\cdot2^{2n-1} + 1
=3\cdot2^{2n-1}+2^{2n-1}+1.$$

Comment: You missed the $+1$ in the left-most term, wasn't it?

Comment: Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

This response is used to indicate that the OP (i.e. original poster) could have taken an entirely different approach to the underlying problem:

> I need to show that $2^n+1$ is divisible by $3$ for odd $n$’s.

This approach will use the fact that for $~a,b,n,p \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ that $~a \equiv b \pmod{p} \implies a^n \equiv b^n \pmod{p}.~$

This may be shown by noting that $~a \equiv b \pmod{p} \implies \exists ~k \in \Bbb{Z}~$ such that $~a = b + pk.~$

This implies that

$$a^n = (b + pk)^n = \sum_{r=0}^n b^{n-r} (pk)^r \binom{n}{r}.$$

Therefore,

$$a^n - b^n = \sum_{r=1}^n b^{n-r} (pk)^r \binom{n}{r}. \tag1 $$

In (1) above, every term on the RHS has a factor of $~p~$ in it.  Therefore, the RHS is $~\equiv 0 \pmod{p}.~$  Therefore, $~a^n \equiv b^n \pmod{p}.$

---

Note that $~2^1 \equiv 2 \pmod{3}~$ and that $~2^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}.~$

Then, employing modular arithmetic, $~2^{2n} \equiv 1^n \equiv 1 \pmod{3}.~$

Therefore, $~2^{2n+1} = (2 \times 2^n) \equiv (2 \times 1) = 2 \pmod{3}.~$

Therefore $~2^{2n+1} + 1 \equiv (2 + 1) = 3 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}.$

Answer (score 0):

RandomGuy has given a general approach.

You can verify this particular formula by just multiplying out the the terms on the right hand side and noting that only $2^n+1$ are left.

Divisibility by 3

Option: Binomial expansion, $n$ is odd.

$(3-1)^n=\sum_{0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}3^{n-k}(-1)^k$; $\binom{n}{k}$ is a positive integer.

All terms on the right hand side have a factor $3$,
except the last term $(-1)^n=-1$ (since $n$ is odd).

Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  you reported that you have studied geometric progressions.  What is the sum of a geometric series with initial term $2^{n-1}$, ratio $\frac{-1}2$, and final term $1$?

Answer (score -1):

I got it,it is really simple and stupid but I haven’t managed to understand it for some reason.
It may be related to the fact that I wasn’t doing problems with negative coefficient,so I found formula with alternating + and - sign unfamiliar and strange.Thanks all people here for help and effort.